# Is the Powershell backwards compatible with the standard command prompt?

Tags: unix, powershell, command-line

Is there any potential issues with using the powershell but executing all the traditional commands associated with the old Windows command shell?  I am also concerned that batch files written in the old style remain unaffected.

It makes complete sense that Microsoft will have thought of all of this; however, I just need to be cautious as we are running old style scripts in a production environment.  I don't want to worry that powershell might pose any issues.

We are scheduling jobs (running batch files) via Windows Task Scheduler.  I assume these jobs will be just fine whether the files are run as though submitted via the Powershell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it is not completely backwards compatible. You can however run a cmd session within powershell then get compatibility. If you are running a batch file as a scheduled task, then the batch file would be processed in a cmd session and not powershell anyway so they shouldn't have an issue.